# Save one page of UIScrollView to image

Tags: iphone, ios, image, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I have an `UIWebView`. After loading data to UIWebView, my `UIWebView` can scroll horizontally, and i enable paging for my scrollView in web view.

My question is:

is there any way to save a page in scrollView in UIWebView to image? I mean, i will get 5 images for 5 pages of scrollView(content size = 5 pages)

Comment: if you have a scrollview or webview,etc anything in applcation but if you want to capture and save current screen with image object then use my code bellow...

Comment: if UIScrollView in web view  has content size larger than the frame of uiscrollview in web view, the image is not complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can save your screen like this way:-

```
 -(IBAction)savebutn:(id)sender
 {
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *saveImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(saveImage);
NSFileManager *fileMan = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",imagename];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *pdfFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
[fileMan createFileAtPath:pdfFileName contents:imageData attributes:nil];


 }
```

your Image will be save in your document directory with .png extension

Answer (score 0):

This Code Useful when user want to capture current view ScreenShot and share or save this image....

```
- (UIImage *)captureView {

//hide controls if needed
CGRect rect = [self.view bounds];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:context];   
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;

}
```

see my blog,... http://parasjoshi3.blogspot.in/2012/06/captureimagescreenshot-of-view.html

:)

Comment: this sample code will save current view to image, i already tried, however, my UIWebView has content size larger than screen size, so my saved image has empty content of UIWebView

Comment: no, i use [self.view bounds];
my view has a tabbar and a uiwebview. and my uiwebview has content size larger than screen size, when i use your code above, the output image include only tabbar...

Comment: try this line CGRect rect = [yourScrollView bounds]; insted of this line CGRect rect = [self.view bounds]; with my code...

Answer (score 0):

```
CGRect rect = [webview bounds];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size,YES,0.0f);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[webview.layer renderInContext:context];   
UIImage *capturedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

This helps to capture the current image